# Azure pipelines set environment using if condition

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on a dacpac deployment pipeline and I need DBA to approve the stage if script finds certain things in the sql script.
So my idea is that I have a powershell script setting a output variable in one stage and then based one the output of that variable I either set the deployment environment to one value or the other.

My problem is that I am not getting my if statement to evaluate true even if the variable is what it is supposed to be.

How I test this and what is the problem.

Template file where I test the if statement and where I will change the environment:

`deploy_dacpac.yml`

```
parameters:
  - name: sqlWarn
    type: string

jobs:
  - deployment: 'deploy_dacpac'
    displayName: 'Deploy the dacpac'
    environment: 'Valters Code'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          pool:
            name: 'SQL-TEST'
          steps:
            - powershell: Write-Output ${{ parameters.sqlWarn }}
            - ${{ if eq(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning') }}:
                - powershell: Write-Output "nice"
            - ${{ else }}:
                - powershell: Write-Output "not nice"
            - template: '../steps/dacpac-deploy-steps.yml'
```

Partial part of where the parameter is set:

```
  - stage: TEST
    displayName: TEST (SANDBOX)
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deployDacpac, true) }}:
      dependsOn: PRE_TEST
    ${{ else }}:
      dependsOn: BUILD
    variables:
    - template: variables/test.yml
    - group: Container Registry
    - name: sqlWarn
      value: $[stageDependencies.PRE_TEST.check_for_anomalies.outputs['check_for_anomalies.sql-warn']]
    jobs:
      - ${{ if eq(parameters.deployDacpac, true) }}:
        - template: ../common/jobs/deploy_dacpac.yml
          parameters:
            sqlWarn: $(sqlWarn)
```

For some reason it always outputs `not nice` result. Even though the parameter output is `warning`

I have tried to change `${{ else }}` to `${{ if ne(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning') }}`

I think I need to add that my main goal is to set environment based on the if condition

```
${{if eq(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning')}} 
environment: 'environment1' 
${{if ne(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning')}} 
environment: 'environment2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the syntax to [conditionally run a step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-run-a-step), which uses a compile time expression (note the `${{}}` syntax). This means that the evaluation of the value will happen right after the pipeline has been queued, before any job is being executed. At this point of time, the `sqlWarn` parameter has not been set yet. That's why you are seeing this behavior.

As the value for `sqlWarn` is generated in a job, you need to do the evaluation at runtime. For this you can use the [`condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) parameter:

```yaml
steps:
  - powershell: Write-Output "nice"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning'))
  - powershell: Write-Output "not nice"
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning'))
```

Comment: Would this be the same reason why I cannot set environment  based on the if condition as well?
For example:
${{if eq(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning')}}
environment: 'environment1'
${{if ne(parameters.sqlWarn, 'warning')}}
environment: 'environment2'

Comment: @ValtersZilinskis yes, this could be the same reason